# Unable to sendEmail using firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nodemailer

Unable to sendEmail after firestore document creation. I am trying to send a notification email to webapp admin's email once the document on firestore is created. However facing following issues.

**index.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin")
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

admin.initializeApp()


//google account credentials used to send email
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: '*****@gmail.com',
        pass: '******'
    }
});


exports.sendEmail = functions.firestore
    .document('stories/{sId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {

        const mailOptions = {
            from: `*******@gmail.com`,
            to: snap.data().email,
            subject: 'contact form message',
            html: `<h1>Order Confirmation</h1>
                                <p>
                                   <b>Email: </b>${snap.data().email}<br>
                                </p>`
        };


        return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, data) => {
            if (error) {
                return res.send(error.toString());
            }
            var data = JSON.stringify(data)
            return res.send(`Sent! ${data}`);
        });
    
    });
```

**Firebase Functions logs**

*sendEmail
Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions

sendEmail
Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value*

I am assuming it is safe to ignore the Billing message in logs as it is not mandatory to have a billing plan ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show images of text.  Copy the text into the question so it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: Done, thanks Doug. Would you able to provide any pointers ?

Comment: Sending emails requires external network access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you that your code returned something other than a promise or value as required.  The problem is the way you're using `transporter.sendMail()`.  According to the [nodemailer documentation](https://nodemailer.com/usage/#sending-mail), `sendMail` will only return a promise if you **don't** pass a callback method (which you *are* doing) otherwise it returns undefined.  So your function is returning undefined.

What you should do instead remove the callback parameter and instead handle the results from the returned promise.  You can also return the promise from the function.

```
    return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
    .then(data => {
        // decide what you want to do on success
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // decide what you want to do on failure
    });
```